# Sign into Google Play Services, lag/freezes/delay gameplay. Using LibGDX for Android App

Tags: android, libgdx, google-play-games

I have made an Android app using LibGDX and implemented Google Play Game Services, specifically for Leaderboards.

I have noticed that when I am not signed into Google Play Game Services, gameplay is smooth and there is not slowdowns.

However, as soon as I sign in, the gameplay is affected with lag/freezes/delay every second or so. It delays in very short bursts.

If I close the app and open it again, everything is back to normal. I assume because the app has signed out of Google Play Game Services.

This is the login code used:

```
    @Override
public void loginGPGS() {
    try {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
                gameHelper.beginUserInitiatedSignIn();
            }
        });
    } catch (final Exception ex) {
    }
}
```

Any thoughts and ideas on this issue?

Thanks